# Can we segment more than one movie file using mediafilesegmenter tool - HTTP Live Streaming

Tags: iphone

Is there any way to achieve segmenting from more than one movie file using mediafilesegmenter. I want to create one prog_index.m3u8 file from multiple movie files. 
If mediafilesegmenter doesn't support, can anyone suggest alternate approach to achieve this.

Thanks in advance to all the viewers who takes time to look into this query .

Thanks
Sudheer

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any help for segmenting more than one video file using mediafielsegmenter but found a solution to my issue.
As we know that mediafilesegmenter tool will generate a prog_index.m3u8 file by default after segmenting the movie file, here I'm creating a new index file with contents appended from prog_index.m3u8 and updating the new index file when a new movie file is segmented. This has solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

`MediaFileSegmenter` is not meant for combining more than one files. It's used for segmenting video files.

If you want to combine multiple files you can use `ffmpeg`. It's a very simple and efficient tool for performing various operations on video files.

From `ffmpeg` documentation, 
Create a file `mylist.txt` with all the files you want to have concatenated in the following form:

```
file '/path/to/file1'
file '/path/to/file2'
file '/path/to/file3'
```

Note that these can be either relative or absolute paths. Then you can stream copy or re-encode your files:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy output
```

The `-safe 0` above is not required if the paths are relative.

you can find more on `concatenation` [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate).

Once you have combined the files. Segment them using `mediafilesegmenter`, you don't need to manually append index files within `prog_index.m3u8`.